# Envio de dados entre Activitys com PutExtra - Gerenciamento

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho três telas:

- Main
- Activity 2
- Activity 3

Na primeira Activity (Main) eu mando um dado por putExtra para a Activity 2 (id usuario). A Activity 2 é a tela de perfil, e em determinado momento eu mando para uma terceira Activity (ex: tela visualização foto).

Até ai funciona com o envio PutExtra e GetExtra. O problema está quando eu clico no botão voltar, está dando um erro e parando a aplicação.

Até já procurei e tentei implementar algo como startActivityForResult, mas não compreendi direito e não funciona.

O problema está especificamente na volta da Activity 3 para Activity2, pois mesmo eu tentando enviar o codigo do usuario novamente para essa tela está dando conflito, pois a Activity 2 já tem em seu inicio um GetExtra, que por sua vez veio da Activity Main.

Exemplo:

Activity Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnIrAct2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnIrAct2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIrAct2);
        btnIrAct2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent2.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
                startActivity(intent2);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnIrAct3;
    private String mId_Empresa = null;
    static final int SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST = 1;
    private TextView tvResultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        /*  Recebe id de outra tela*/
        mId_Empresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");

        tvResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAct2);
        tvResultado.setText(mId_Empresa);

        btnIrAct3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIrAct3);
        btnIrAct3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent3 = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
                intent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent3.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
                startActivityForResult(intent3, SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST );

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String resultBack = data.getStringExtra("id_empresa");
        }
    }

}
```

Activity 3:

```
public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String idEmpresa = null;
    private TextView resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*  Recebe id de outra tela*/
        idEmpresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");

        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAct3);
        resultado.setText(idEmpresa);


    }

    @Override
    public void finish()
    {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        super.finish();
    }

}
```

Preciso resolver esse conflito. Enviar o mesmo dado como PutExtra da Activity 3 para Activity 2, porém a Activity 2 já espera um GetExtra da Activity Main.

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando a flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` nas suas intents que abrem as activities 2 e 3. Ao colocar essa flag, você remove as activities anteriores da sua pilha. Se esse não for o comportamento desejado, você tem que remover essa flag(`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`) e, então, não vai precisar do `startActivityForResult()` da activity 2 para a 3.

Mais detalhes em: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)